# OAuth2 Client Credentials flow for Microsoft Graph

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The OAuth2 specification for Client Credentials (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) says that "The authorization server **MUST** support the HTTP Basic authentication scheme for authenticating clients that were issued a client password" but **MAY** support including the client credentials in the body of the message.

I can see from the Microsoft Graph API documentation that they describe using this latter method.

However, does this mean that the Basic Authentication approach is NOT supported or just that the alternative approach is preferred?

Thanks.

Comment: You should check the latest documentation on client credential flow:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: Thanks for the response. So it looks like the answer to my question would be a "no" then. The documentation also, as far as I can find, does not specify much about the response received for a resource request when a token has expired. I'm hoping it is a 401 with a suitable "error" and "error_description". Given that you have better luck than I have finding the right place, do you know where I might find info about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see `token_type` in the [response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#successful-response-1).

> token_type    Indicates the token type value. The only type that
> Microsoft identity platform supports is **bearer**.

For your question in the comment, if the access token has expired, it will show an 401 error.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to give you half a tick? :-) The comment on the expired token is very helpful thank you but the Bearer token is for sending the token when retrieving the resource. I am talking about supporting Basic Authentication when sending the client credentials to obtain the access token in the first stage.

Comment: @MarkHagan Sorry for the misunderstanding. I think it's not available. We need to follow AAD document:)